# Ionic: NgModel not working on Page Compoent?

Tags: ionic-framework

ngModel is not working in an ionic app.
FormsModule and CommonModule are imported in the page.module.ts.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j68b7.png)

usage is as follows
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pE3r8.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFq3A.png)

Answer (score 0):

**this is an example demonstrating to use ngModel in angular:**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'example-app',
  template: `
    <input [(ngModel)]="name" #ctrl="ngModel" required>

    <p>Value: {{ name }}</p>
    <p>Valid: {{ ctrl.valid }}</p>

    <button (click)="setValue()">Set value</button>
  `,
})
export class SimpleNgModelComp {
  name: string = '';

  setValue() {
    this.name = 'Nancy';
  }
}
```

> When using the ngModel within  tags, you'll also need to supply
> a name attribute so that the control can be registered with the parent
> form under that name